# Cesar cipher only prints out the first letter

Tags: python, for-loop

the following code should print out the shifted character from text but it only prints out the first letter

```
def encrypt(text,s):
    result = ""
   # transverse the plain text

    for i in range(len(text)):


      char = text[i]
      # Encrypt uppercase characters in plain text

      if (char.isupper()):
         result += chr((ord(char) + s-65) % 26 + 65)
      # Encrypt lowercase characters in plain text
      else:
         result += chr((ord(char) + s - 97) % 26 + 97)
      return result
#check the above function
text = "CEASER CIPHER DEMO"
s = 4

print ("Plain Text : " + text)
print ("Shift pattern : " + str(s))
print ("Cipher: " + encrypt(text,s))
```

Comment: The for loop in `encrypt()` contains a `return` statement, so the loop will only ever run once.  Perhaps the `return` shouldn't be inside the loop?

Answer (score 1):

`return` immediately returns from the function, ending the loop. You want to shift your return up an indent level, so it only returns once the loop is complete

Comment: Thanks bud, that was driving me nuts